# Using the built-in C++ function to make parameter variable "seat" upper case

Tags: c++

Am trying to make the parameter variable "seat" upper case but I keep getting errors I don't want to include bits/stdc++.h header file but am stuck trying to figure it out. I need guidance on how to make it work

**Error states 'transform': identifier not found**
these are the includes i have in the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cctype>
```

```
bool releaseSeat(string seat)
{


    bool releaseSeatOK = false;

    transform(seat.begin(), seat.end(), seat.begin(), ::toupper);

    string passengerName = showOccupant(seat);

    if (passengerName.compare("seat_01A") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_01B") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_01C") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_01D") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_02A") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_02B") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_02C") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_02D") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_03A") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_03B") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_03C") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_03D") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }

    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_04A") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (seat.compare("04B") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "seat_04B";
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_04B") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_04C") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }
    else if (passengerName.compare("seat_04D") == 0)
    {
        passengerName = "empty";
        releaseSeatOK = true;
    }

    return releaseSeatOK;
}
```

I've tried what I know based on my knowledge so far since am just starting c++
This is part of 1000 lines of code I can't include every line, am just getting errors on this line

Comment: What errors? Show the includes you do have. Consider removing code that does not matter, like over a dozen similar comparisons that don't seem to use the variable you're having the error with.

Comment: For reference https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform is in the `algorithm` header.

Comment: am not supposed to add or remove any header, I have to use the already provided headers given to me

Comment: Is there a way to rewrite the code to work with the headers given to me?

Comment: Use a `for` loop if you can't include `algorithm` for whatever silly reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you include `<algorithm>`? `std::transform` is found in `<algorithm>` so if you didn't include it C++ doesn't know what `std::transform` is, hence the error.

**Edit**: I see you don't have `<algorithm>` included, so just add `#include <algorithm>` to the top of your code and the error should disappear.

**Edit 2**: Just iterate over each character in `seat` and capitalize them, like so:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < seat.length(); i++)
{
    seat[i] = toupper(seat[i]);
}
```

`std::transform` is not necessary in this case.